# Uncaught exceptions in Tomcat print to localhost.[date].log instead of catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, catalina.out

I'm running tomcat 6.0.20 (with spring, if that matters) and can't seem to get stack traces  from uncaught exceptions thrown from within my code to print to catalina.out.

I'm trying to mimic the output that you see in the eclipse console. When I deploy a war on a production server and start tomcat, most of the output goes to catalina.out, but stack traces from exceptions thrown within my own code goes to tomcat/logs/localhost.[date].log.

How can I get all of the relevant logging to go to one file (similar to eclipse's console)?

I'm starting the server by simply running tomcat/bin/startup.sh

Comment: Are they present in stderr.log file?

Comment: Not sure where that file is - I don't see it in tomcat/logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/logging.properties`

The default would have the catalina engine log to catalina.log and the localhost logging to localhost.log

like below

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
```

Take your pick and edit `.prefix` to point to the one you want.

**Update**
`catalina.out` is explicitly referenced as shown below in the `catalina.sh` start script (but not in the corresponsing bat files) - which is why I dont see the .out file on windows but only on *nix systems

`"$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out 2>&1`

*Personally* I prefer the Catalina engine logs being separate from my application logs

Comment: I see how that controls what goes to catalina.[date].log and localhost.[date].log, but what decides the contents of catalina.out?

Comment: I heard catalina.out is "console output" (standard error and standard output) while localhost.log is "server logging" (maybe uncaught exceptions?)